# Is there a way to make a query follow a hierarchy in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite, amazon-web-services

I have a set of data where I have a bunch of sellers but we have a hierarchy of sellers which we prefer and would like to select the best available seller for each product.

```
ID |ITEM   | price   | Seller
===========================
1  |Laptop | 100     | eBay
2  |Laptop | 125     | Amazon
3  |Apple  | 5       | Amazon
```

So when I query out this data for Laptops, I want it each item with the top available seller. And the hierarchy that I have for sellers is 1. ebay 2. Amazon so in essence it would only return the first and the third records.

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get that with subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl t1
WHERE (t1.id, t1.item, t1.price) IN
    (SELECT t2.id, t2.item, t2.price
     FROM tbl t2
     WHERE t1.id = t2.id
     ORDER BY t2.price
     LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Query tested in Oracle, MySQL and SQLite:

```
select s.* from sellers s
  join (select item, min(price) mp from sellers group by item) ms
    on s.item = ms.item and s.price = ms.mp
```

<sup>[MySQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d248/1), [SQLite Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/45f48/1)</sup>

For Oracle you can use alternative query, it should be faster:

```
select id, item, price, seller
  from ( select s.*, min(price) over (partition by item) min_price from sellers s )
  where price = min_price
```